# How do I get content to display using Views and Panels?

Tags: views, panels

I've created a custom view to display two different content types and now want to override the node display with this new view. I tried using [this tutorial](http://groups.drupal.org/node/92009) to do so with Panels, but I always get no content. Not a completely white screen, just a title and nothing beneath it. I am able to add other content using Panels directly, so I think it must be a problem with the way Views and Panels are interfacing. Any idea what I need to do to fix this?

I have tried:
- changing the output format of the view to 'Panel Fields' (as opposed to 'Content').
- clearing and re-clearing my browser's cache.

I'm using Drupal 7.12, Chaos Tools 7.x-1.0-rc2, Panels 7.x-3.2 and Views 7.x-3.3

Comment: Do you have a "content pane" display type in your view?

Comment: what is the views "display option" set to? Is it a block or a page?

Comment: Will be any problem if you do this without panels?

Answer (score 1):

For Views to work in panels, you should create a `Content Pane` in your view.

You will likely be using a contextual filter if it's a node / user / taxonomy view so add it, and check `provide default: content id` from url (for a node).

Then in the Pane Settings section, click Argument Input. You will see your contextual filter listed. Choose "From Context", "Content ID".

Your view should now work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your view is applying a filter that is filtering out all the content. Check to make sure that the View you have set up has the right filter criteria.

Comment: Nope - that looks okay. Filtering only on the particular content type I want and that it's published.

Comment: I should also say, that the View itself looks just peachy when I navigate to it directly (as opposed to having it supplant a node).

Comment: I'm sorry then idk, i don't have much xp working with Panels

Answer (score 0):

Create your content type views as block just enabled the block in panels dsiplay wherever you want